# WPF - how to prevent duplicated AutomationId in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, automation, ui-automation, white-framework

I am using AutomationId and white for testing and I have encountered a problem recently that arrived from the automation team due to failure of some tests consistently.

I have some DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeDataModel}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameTitle}" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="NameTitleId"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="NameId"/>
        <Button Content="Apply" Command="{Binding ApplyCommand}" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ApplyCommandId"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

When creating the AutomationId's, the inner controls recieve AutomationId's, but that means that **every instance of that DataTemplate that is being created, all AutomationId's will be duplicated**.

This causes tests to fail due to clicking of reading from the wrong control.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just add your automation IDs as properties in `SomeDataModel` and bind to them:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeDataModel}">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameTitle}"
               AutomationProperties.AutomationId="{Binding NameTitleId}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
               AutomationProperties.AutomationId="{Binding NameId}"/>
    <Button Content="Apply" Command="{Binding ApplyCommand}"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="{Binding ApplyCommandId}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with this solution is how to generate the AutomationIds on the DataModels in runtime so they will not conflict with others.

Comment: You could try the [ObjectIDGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.objectidgenerator?view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

Comment: As far as I can tell, ObjectIDGenerator does not provide deterministic output, so you will end up with different IDs ever time you run the program, which defeats the purpose of adding IDs.

Answer (score 0):

If your data model has a unique id you can bind to it like so. (Let's assume Name is unique).

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeDataModel}">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameTitle}"
               AutomationProperties.AutomationId="{Binding Name,StringFormat='NameTitleTextBlockFor_{0}'}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
               AutomationProperties.AutomationId="{Binding Name,StringFormat='NameTextBlockFor_{0}'}"/>
    <Button Content="Apply" Command="{Binding ApplyCommand}"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="{Binding Name,StringFormat='ApplyButtonFor_{0}'}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: The code you posted looks, superficially, *very similar* to that in the [answer from I33t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53046044/10871073). You should add some explanation to highlight the differences and the improvements they make over that answer.